# window.frames[0].document.onkeydown not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, onkeydown

I have this line not working in Firefox (works perfectly fine in IE and Chrome)

```
ste.frame.document.onkeydown=function(e) {
    alert('a');
};
```

here ste.frame is a window object [object Window]. I tried

```
window.frames[0].document.onkeydown=function(e){
    alert('b');
}
```

Also working in IE and Chrome and not working in Firefox. I guess if the second one works, the first one will work either.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would been better if you have posted your code at jsfiddle.net, but have you tried ´window.frames[0].onKeyDown´? Does the error console show an error message?

Comment: Hi! Yeah, I've tried that. No luck. Error console does not provide any error messages. If I make it window.frames[1] then it gives error saying that the object does not exist. Otherwise - no errors

Comment: for some reason it works fine in jsfiddle.net, but not working directly. This is the code:
<iframe></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.frames[0].document.onkeydown=function(e){
  alert('a');
 }
</script>

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted in the comments above doesn't work because you're setting the listener before the subframe is done loading its about:blank document.  So you're setting a listener on a temporary document that then goes away.

Gecko is likely to change behavior here at some point to more closely match what you see in IE and WebKit now that the HTML5 spec actually defines how about:blank should behave....

Answer (score 0):

I spended almost an hour to find a solution, but I couldn't. I think the reason is, that the Mozilla foundation has implented just the basics of IFrame object, so you can't assign an eventhandler. Compare to eventhandler you can modify css styles (see this [example](http://xkr.us/articles/dom/iframe-document/)).

> window.frames[0].document.onkeydown=function(e){
>       alert('b'); }

I used the DOM-Inspector to figure out on which object this code does point. In my eyes, it points to global object of DOM of Firefox.

PS: In case I'm wrong, correct me please.